# what are all available identity verification types in docusign?

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I am trying to get all available types of identity verficaions in docusign, also their `defaultName`s, but I never found a documentaion with a full list (see [here](https://www.docusign.com/products/identify?_gl=1*w11jpr*_gcl_au*MjkyNzgyNDUyLjE2OTcyMDQ5NTY.*_ga*MTcwODcyNTk4My4xNjg3OTUyMTU3*_ga_1TZ7S9D6BQ*MTcwMzY5MDA1MS4zMy4xLjE3MDM2OTEyNjguNjAuMC4w&_ga=2.29032248.50958936.1703685643-1708725983.1687952157) and [here](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&_gl=1*u4ck0h*_gcl_au*MjkyNzgyNDUyLjE2OTcyMDQ5NTY.*_ga*MTcwODcyNTk4My4xNjg3OTUyMTU3*_ga_1TZ7S9D6BQ*MTcwMzY5MDA1MS4zMy4xLjE3MDM2OTE3OTcuNjAuMC4w&_ga=2.266493194.50958936.1703685643-1708725983.1687952157&bundleId=gav1643676262430&topicId=kzp1578456318101.html&_LANG=enus)).

I know, that I can use the function `getAccountIdentityVerification` (see [here](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/accounts/identityverifications/list/)) to list all available method for a specific account, but it does not give me all supported types.

In my case: I have an app and users have different accounts with different methods, so I need to know all possible methods and thier `defaultName`s to be able to handle any selection of the users.
The behaviour of my app changes based on the defaultName of the selection.

Any Idea how to get "`defaultName`" of all available identity verification methods?

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing, here:

"DocuSign ID Verification" - also known as IDV, this is a premium feature, most users won't have it, it costs money per transaction. See code example - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/id-verification/

"Intuit KBA" - also knowns simply as KBA (Knowledge Based Authentication). See code example - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/knowledge-based-authentication/

"Phone Authentication" - this can be either via SMS/text or a voice call. See code example - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/phone-auth/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that is not all, one of my clients gets the followings (defaultName in the json response): "DocuSign Knowledge-Based Authentication", "DocuSign ID Verification with Liveness", "DocuSign ID Verification", "Phone Authentication". These are four and perhaps not all. How to get the rest?

Comment: Need to contact support or sales, as these are premium features.